# Setting maximum number of Columns for ListView

Tags: listview

How do we fix the maximum number of columns for a particular ListView control?
Is there any thing like this:

```
listViewControl.MaximumColumns = 3;
```

Comment: Can you clarify the why? What is the purpose? If you want to restrict what how many columns the user is able to add, that is up to you, the developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the [Windows ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(VS.80).aspx), the maximum is how many columns you [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3dfa3sx(VS.80).aspx) to it.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest, inheriting from the ListView class and then create a method in it say

```
    public ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection Columns
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public void AddColumns(string _columnName1, string _columnName2)
    {
        base.Columns.Add(_columnName);
    }
```

to "hide" the Columns property as well as limiting the addition to only 2 columns- not less, not more.

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass in information that has three entries into the adapter for the ListView. For instance, an array with length of 3.

```
Object[] sArray = {"", "", ""};
ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sArray);
setListAdapter(adp);
```